# Filter generated permutations in python

Tags: python, permutation, permute

I want to generate permutations of elements in a list, but only keep a set where each element is on each position only once.

For example `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` could be a user list and I want 3 permutations. A good set would be:

```
[1,2,3,5,4,6]
[2,1,4,6,5,3]
[3,4,5,1,6,2]
```

However, one could not add, for example, [1,3,2,6,5,4] to the above, as there are two permutations in which 1 is on the first position twice, also 5 would be on the 5th position twice, however other elements are only present on those positions once.

My code so far is :

```
# this simply generates a number of permutations specified by number_of_samples

def generate_perms(player_list, number_of_samples):
    myset = set()
    while len(myset) < number_of_samples:
         random.shuffle(player_list)
         myset.add(tuple(player_list))
    return [list(x) for x in myset]

# And this is my function that takes the stratified samples for permutations.
def generate_stratified_perms(player_list, number_of_samples):
    user_idx_dict = {}
    i = 0

    while(i < number_of_samples):
        perm = generate_perms(player_list, 1)
        for elem in perm:
            if not user_idx_dict[elem]:
                user_idx_dict[elem] = [perm.index(elem)]
            else:
                user_idx_dict[elem] += [perm.index(elem)]
        [...]
    return total_perms
```

but I don't know how to finish the second function.

So in short, I want to give my function a number of permutations to generate, and the function should give me that number of permutations, in which no element appears on the same position more than the others (once, if all appear there once, twice, if all appear there twice, etc).

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? What part are you struggling with?

Comment: @AMC I don't know how to finish the function, I was thinking to put the indices of each seen user (from all previous permutations) in a dictionary, then check for any new permutation if the user has been seen in that position or not, but this would be insanely costly, hence the [...] part in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's starting by solving the case of generating `n` or fewer rows first. In that case, your output must be a [Latin rectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_rectangle) or a [Latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square). These are easy to generate: start by constructing a Latin square, shuffle the rows, shuffle the columns, and then keep just the first `r` rows. The following always works for constructing a Latin square to start with:

```
1 2 3 ... n
2 3 4 ... 1
3 4 5 ... 2
... ... ...
n 1 2 3 ...
```

Shuffling rows is a lot easier than shuffling columns, so we'll shuffle the rows, then take the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose), then shuffle the rows again. Here's an implementation in Python:

```py
from random import shuffle

def latin_rectangle(n, r):
    square = [
        [1 + (i + j) % n for i in range(n)]
        for j in range(n)
    ]
    shuffle(square)
    square = list(zip(*square)) # transpose
    shuffle(square)
    return square[:r]
```

Example:

```py
>>> latin_rectangle(5, 4)
[(2, 4, 3, 5, 1),
 (5, 2, 1, 3, 4),
 (1, 3, 2, 4, 5),
 (3, 5, 4, 1, 2)]
```

Note that this algorithm can't generate *all possible* Latin squares; by construction, the rows are cyclic permutations of each other, so you won't get Latin squares in other [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square#Equivalence_classes_of_Latin_squares). I'm assuming that's OK since generating a uniform probability distribution over all possible outputs isn't one of the question requirements.

The upside is that this is guaranteed to work, and consistently in `O(n^2)` time, because it doesn't use [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) or [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking_search).

---

Now let's solve the case where `r > n`, i.e. we need more rows. Each column can't have equal frequencies for each number unless `r % n == 0`, but it's simple enough to guarantee that the frequencies in each column will differ by at most 1. Generate enough Latin squares, put them on top of each other, and then slice `r` rows from it. For additional randomness, it's safe to shuffle those `r` rows, but only after taking the slice.

```py
def generate_permutations(n, r):
    rows = []
    while len(rows) < r:
        rows.extend(latin_rectangle(n, n))
    rows = rows[:r]
    shuffle(rows)
    return rows
```

Example:

```py
>>> generate_permutations(5, 12)
[(4, 3, 5, 2, 1),
 (3, 4, 1, 5, 2),
 (3, 1, 2, 4, 5),
 (5, 3, 4, 1, 2),
 (5, 1, 3, 2, 4),
 (2, 5, 1, 3, 4),
 (1, 5, 2, 4, 3),
 (5, 4, 1, 3, 2),
 (3, 2, 4, 1, 5),
 (2, 1, 3, 5, 4),
 (4, 2, 3, 5, 1),
 (1, 4, 5, 2, 3)]
```

---

This uses the numbers `1` to `n` because of the formula `1 + (i + j) % n` in the first list comprehension. If you want to use something other than the numbers `1` to `n`, you can take it as a list (e.g. `players`) and change this part of the list comprehension to `players[(i + j) % n]`, where `n = len(players)`.

Answer (score 0):

If runtime is not that important I would go for the lazy way and generate all possible permutations (`itertools` can do that for you) and then filter out all permutations which do not meet your requirements.

Here is one way to do it.

```
import itertools

def permuts (l, n):
    all_permuts = list(itertools.permutations(l))
    picked = []

    for a in all_permuts:
        valid = True
        for p in picked:
            for i in range(len(a)):
                if a[i] == p[i]:
                    valid = False
                    break

        if valid:
            picked.append (a)

        if len(picked) >= n:
            break

    print (picked)


permuts ([1,2,3,4,5,6], 3)
```

Comment: could the filtering be done earlier? As I have to generate 10000 - 100 000 permutations.

Comment: Sure, you just need an extra if condition which breaks the loop if your number of permutations is reached. I edited the example. But anyway, generating 100000 permutations is a tough task. Even without filtering this would be very expensive in terms of runtime. Complexity is O(n!)